# Number of messages in 'unbounded_buffer'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, parallel-processing, visual-studio-2010, concurrency-runtime

The class `Concurrency::unbounded_buffer` can store any number of messages. But how to know number of pending (not received) messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no functionality built in to do this.

What you can do is atomically increment/decrement an integer alongside it, but know that this won't be a reliable count (only a ballpark) if it's being accessed concurrently.

```
long count;
Concurrency::unbounded_buffer<T> buffer;

if(Concurrency::send(buffer, T()))
{
    long new_count = _InterlockedIncrement(&count);
}
```

And elsewhere:

```
T value = Concurrency::receive(buffer);
long new_count = _InterlockedDecrement(&count);
```

You'll find the _Interlocked functions in `<intrin.h>`.

Comment: Yes, you are right - there is no existing accessibe function/member to gain this information. I found out `_M_message_buffer` if type `_Queue`. The `_Queue` class is having `_Count` method. But unfortunately, this variable (of type `_Queue`) is declared as private in `unbounded_buffer` class